# In jquery password show/hide the if-else condition is not working on button cick

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am new to jQuery.

Simply I want to build a password show/hide program.

I have written some code (below), and the first time the program works correctly - the password is showing after clicking on "Show" button. But then the "Hide" feature is not working.

In my code the `if` part is running each time but the `else` part never executes. What's wrong here?

```js
$("#btn").click(function() {

  if ($("#pass").attr("type", "password")) {
    $("#pass").attr("type", "text");
    $("#btn").attr("value", "Hide")
  } else {
    $("#pass").attr("type", "password");
    $("#btn").attr("value", "Show")
  }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Password : <input type="password" id="pass">
<input type="button" id="btn" value="Show">
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! The full content of your question must be in your question, not just linked. Links rot, making the question and its answers useless to people in the future, and people shouldn't have to go off-site to help you. Put a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) **in** the question, ideally using Stack Snippets (the `<>` toolbar button) to make it runnable ([here's how to create one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-do-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do-tha)).

Comment: please show your code as text **within your question**. Then it's easily searchable, copyable and even runnable (for those of us who want to use it for an answer, or to test it), and will not disappear or change in a few weeks (making the question useless for future reader). Press the "edit" button to amend your question and paste the code. You can use the [formatting tools](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) to make it look neat. Thankyou. Otherwise your question is in danger of being closed as [off-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: Please attach the code to the question, don't link it, so we can help you

Comment: I have attached my code

Comment: No, the code must not be **linked from another website**, instead it must be **pasted inside your question**. Re-read the first three comments above, which all mention this. Thanks.

Comment: Is it ok now? I have updated my code

Comment: Yes much better, thanks. And now you can see the solution, below.

Comment: Thanx for quick response ADyson, It works !

Comment: No problem. If it helps you, please remember to mark it as "accepted" (click the green tickbox next to the answer so it turns green), thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is this line:

```
if($("#pass").attr("type","password")){
```

`$("#pass").attr("type","password")` is **setting** the value of the "type" attribute, not comparing it to anything. What you need to do is **get** the value, and then compare it to the value you're checking for:

```
if($("#pass").attr("type") == "password")) {
```

---

Here is a full working example:

N.B. I also added variables to represent the button and textbox, because it's inefficient to repeatedly invoke the jQuery constructor on the same elements.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  var btn = $("#btn");
  
  btn.click(function() {
    var pass = $("#pass");

    if (pass.attr("type") == "password") {
      pass.attr("type", "text");
      btn.attr("value", "Hide")
    } 
    else {
      pass.attr("type", "password");
      btn.attr("value", "Show")
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Password show/hide in Jquery</title>
</head>

<body>
  Password : <input type="password" id="pass">
  <input type="button" id="btn" value="Show">
</body>
</html>
```

You may also wish to review the jQuery documentation to help your understanding: http://api.jquery.com/attr/